# How can i get the tuples to display the sum of each person rather than individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have been given this dictionary whose keys are names; which has tuples with 3 values: in the 3-tuple,  a stock name, number of shares traded for that transaction (int), and price of each share (int).

```
new_dict = {
    'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell' , 20, 50), ('Intel',-10, 60), 
('Apple', 20, 55)],
    'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel',-10, 45), ('IBM',   40, 30), 
('Intel',-10, 35)],
    'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell',  10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell', 
-10, 55)],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple' ,40, 85), ('Apple',-40, 90)]
  }
```

I am creating a function that returns a list of 2-tuples as a result (client, and absolute value of number of shares they sold(negative num) or bought (positive num) total.
**- the list is sorted in decreasing order based on the sum of the number of shares they traded; if two clients trade the same number of shares, they must appear in increasing alphabetical order.**

For new_dict as the dictionary, the output should be [('Alan', 120), ('Dawn', 120), ('Barb', 80), ('Carl', 80)]

Here's what I have done:

```
def most_active_clients(database :{str: (str, int, int)}) -> list:
        result = []
        t = list()

        for key,val in database.items():
            for x in val:
                t.append((key,abs(x[1])))
                for item in t:
                    print(item)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the sum of all x[1]'s and then sort that. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use sorted method

```
new_dict = {
    'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell', 20, 50), ('Intel', -10, 60),
             ('Apple', 20, 55)],
    'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel', -10, 45), ('IBM', 40, 30),
             ('Intel', -10, 35)],
    'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell', 10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell',
                                                                      -10, 55)],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple', 40, 85), ('Apple', -40, 90)]
}


def most_active_clients(new_dict):
    res = []

    for k, v in new_dict.items():
        name = k
        sum = 0
        for l in v:
            sum += abs(l[1])
        res.append((name, sum))

    return sorted(res, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]), reverse=False)


print(most_active_clients(new_dict))
```

I've implemented in the way I find easy.

Line you need is

```
return sorted(res, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]), reverse=False)
```

Comment: Good answer, easy to understand. See my answer for a shorter code that uses a dict comprehension instead of these 2 for loops.

Answer (score 1):

In 2 steps:

- First, compute the absolute sum of shares for each, and store the result in a new dict.
- Then, sort the result.

Here's the code:

```
abs_shares = {(key, sum(abs(x[1]) for x in val)) for key, val in new_dict.items()}
print(sorted(abs_shares, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
```

The output is as expected: `[('Alan', 120), ('Dawn', 120), ('Barb', 80), ('Carl', 80)]`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could get your result:

```
database = {
    'Carl': [('Intel', 30, 40), ('Dell' , 20, 50), ('Intel',-10, 60), 
('Apple', 20, 55)],
    'Barb': [('Intel', 20, 40), ('Intel',-10, 45), ('IBM',   40, 30), 
('Intel',-10, 35)],
    'Alan': [('Intel', 20, 10), ('Dell',  10, 50), ('Apple', 80, 80), ('Dell', 
-10, 55)],
    'Dawn': [('Apple', 40, 80), ('Apple' ,40, 85), ('Apple',-40, 90)]
  }


t = []
for key, val in database.items():
    for x in val:
        t.append((key,abs(x[1])))

a_set = {x[0] for x in t}
res = sorted([(i,sum(x[1] for x in t if x[0] == i)) for i in a_set], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print(res)
# [('Alan', 120), ('Dawn', 120), ('Barb', 80), ('Carl', 80)]
```